# R-Script is not working from QGIS processing toolbox (error massage)

Tags: r, qgis-processing

I would like to use some r-scripts from processing toolbox but I get this error massage:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
â/tmp/RtmpdP9CQf/downloaded_packagesâ
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgdal", dependencies = TRUE) :
installation of package ârgdalâ had non-zero exit status
tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error=function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/raster"
library("raster")
Loading required package: sp
library("rgdal")
Error in library("rgdal") : there is no package called ârgdalâ
Execution halted
```

I installed r-base and r-base-dev 3.4 from CRAN-repository.
R is activated as provider in my QGIS 2.18.9 processing toolbox.

EDIT: I also tryed to install RGDAL via R and got a similar error:

```
downloaded 1.6 MB
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.2-7
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 660
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp3y3vA3/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgdal") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
Error in library(rgdal) : there is no package called ‘rgdal’
```

Comment: What's going on with the special characters in the error message `â`?

Comment: See  the answer in  [StackOverflow: rgdal package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation)

Comment: ...and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141422/error-gdal-config-not-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ubuntu by any chance? I would post as comment to find out but don't have the rep.

I had this problem earlier in the year.  Try

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev 
sudo aptitude install libproj-dev
```

and then installing rgdal.

If you are not using ubuntu I don't have a sure answer but it looks like you need to do some prior set up to get a gdal-config file before installing the package. There is a MAC OS solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333624/trouble-installing-rgdal)

Comment: If you have GDAL 1.x installed, you might add libgdal1-dev.